# Does change of a file in a directory not change the time of the directory?

Tags: find, directory, timestamps

I want to find a file which I created recently, but I don't remember anything and can only guess it is under a directory indirectly with any possible depth.

1. I inspected the times of all the subdirectories of a directory, but
   their times are all older than the time I created the file. I wonder
   why a dir's time isn't updated when a file in it is?
2. If it were you, how would you find the file? By using `find` and
   some option for time? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. For question 1, you also need to tell us your OS and file system, but please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modification time of a directory, like any other file (note how *directories* are called *directories* (a list of *name*/*number* mappings like a phone directory) and not *folders*) is updated whenever the *content* is modified.

That is when a file is added (linked), removed (unlinked), or renamed in it.

Beware that files can be linked to several directories. The system doesn't maintain a live list of which directory any file is linked to (for a given open file descriptor for writing, it doesn't even keep track of which *path* was used to open the file (the components of which can be renamed at any moment anyway)), and if it were and if it were to update the modification time of every directory the file is linked to along with all their ancestors back to `/`, it would end up doing only that.

Generally, your only option is to look for the modification time of every file on the file system.

You can [use `find` as shown by Corentin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187210/22565), or to avoid having to read all those directories, you can look at the modification times of all the inodes in the inode table (though I'm not aware of any tool that does that).

Some file systems, like `btrfs` can give you some clue as to what the most recently modified files were:

```
$ sudo btrfs sub find-new / -1
transid marker was 2273028
$ sudo btrfs sub find-new / 2273020
inode 60319801 file offset 212992 len 4096 disk start 8350875648 offset 0 gen 2273024 flags NONE root/screenlog.2
inode 60319801 file offset 217088 len 28672 disk start 8403632128 offset 0 gen 2273023 flags NONE root/screenlog.2
inode 61045822 file offset 360448 len 4096 disk start 1111568384 offset 0 gen 2273022 flags NONE var/log/apache2/access.log
inode 61045835 file offset 2326528 len 8192 disk start 7824994304 offset 0 gen 2273024 flags NONE var/log/syslog
inode 61045840 file offset 57344 len 8192 disk start 1517305856 offset 0 gen 2273023 flags NONE var/log/kern.log
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks. I read several times "Beware that files can be linked to several directories. The system doesn't maintain a live list of which directory any file is linked to (for a given open file descriptor for writing, it doesn't even keep track of which path was used to open the file (the components of which can be renamed at any moment anyway)), and if it were and if it were to update the modification time of every directory the file is linked to along with all their ancestors back to /, it would end up doing only that." I still don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase it maybe?

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
find <PARENT_DIR> -type f -mtime 1
```

With `1` the time of last modification in days (you can prefix it with `-` or `+` to indicate "less than X days" or "more than X days") : so, if you want the the file modified in the last 3 days, you'll do `-mtime -3`