# Timestamps of a directory?

Tags: directory, timestamps

1. About mtime of a directory, from Stéphane Chazelas's reply
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187231/674

   > The modification time of a directory, like any other file (note how
   >   directories are called directories (a list of name/number mappings
   >   like a phone directory) and not folders) is updated whenever the
   >   content is modified.
   >
   > That is when a file is added (linked), removed (unlinked), or renamed
   >   in it.

   Does it mean that a directory's content about a child file is only
   the filename of the child file, and the number of hardlinks to the
   child file?

   If not, what other info of a child file is in the
   content of the parent directory?

   In other words, changing what of a child file will also change mtime of its parent directory?
2. When does the atime   of a directory change? I found that neither of
   `ls -l`, `ls -ld` and `cd` changes ctime of a dir. I thought the commands display the directory's content, and therefore reads the directory's content?
3. When does the  ctime of a directory change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of a directory as a text file that looks something like:

```
123:foo.txt
234:bar.txt
123:other-name-for-foo.txt
```

That's all there is (at least in traditional Unix file systems).

`foo.txt` is not a *child* of that directory in that it's not an exclusive relationship. It's just that the file of inode number 123 is referenced in two entries of that directory: with names `foo.txt` and `other-name-for-foo.txt`.

Those two directory entries are also known as two *hard* links to the same file.

```
$ touch foo.txt bar.txt
$ mkdir other-dir
$ ln foo.txt other-name-for-foo.txt
$ ln foo.txt other-dir/whatever
$ ls -i . other-dir
.:
58892735 bar.txt  58958143 other-dir/
58879562 foo.txt  58879562 other-name-for-foo.txt

other-dir:
58879562 whatever
```

`.` and `other-dir` are two files of type *directory*, each containing a number of directory entries. `ls` lists the entries of a directory whose names don't start with `.` and with `-i` includes the inode number.

With `-a` (to include dotfiles), and `-i` (`ls -ai`), that's more or less dumping the content of that *text file* I was mentioning above.

You'll notice that the file of inode 58879562 above is linked once to `other-dir` and twice to `.`. That 58879562 file now has a link-count of 3, but neither `.` nor `other-dir` care about that. That information is stored in the inode of the file and is just for the system to keep track of how many times the file is linked to a directory. If that number falls to 0, the disk space occupied by that file can be reclaimed.

In addition to inode number and name, directories also contain the file type of the file (regular/fifo/directory/symlink/device..., though not for all file systems). That information can be retrieved otherwise (as it's stored in the inode) so is not necessary. It is done mainly for optimisation purposes and because it's possible. It is possible because it is not possible to change the type of a file (contrary to other metadata), so that information stored in the directory is not going to become out-of-sync with the reality.

You'll also notice that the system call to remove a file is not `remove("/foo/bar")` but `unlink("/foo/bar")`. That's because all it does is remove the `bar` entry from the `/foo` directory, it *unlinks* `bar` from `/foo`. That file may still be linked to other (or the same by a different name) directory. It's only going to be removed when its link count reaches zero (when it's no longer linked to any directory).

As to why doing an `ls` doesn't update the access time of a directory, that's probably because your filesystem is mounted with the `noatime` or `relatime` option.

Updating the access-time of a file (directory or other) every time it is read is costly, so many systems give up on that nowadays.

Note that the system, if not the user reads directories all the time.

For instance, when accessing `/foo/bar`, the system needs to read the content of `/` to find `foo` and then `/foo` to find `bar` (though most of the time that information is cached). However, in those cases, the atime is not updated (thankfully), only when user-space processes *explicitely* read the content of a directory like `ls` does.

As to when the `ctime` of a directory is updated, that's the same as for a regular file: when its content is modified (entries added or removed or renamed) or its metadata (except `atime` upon reading) is modified (like upon `chmod`/`chown`, ACL modifications...).

Comment: Thanks. "in those cases, the atime is not updated (thankfully), only when user-space processes explicitely read the content of a directory like ls does." Do you mean `ls` doesn't update atime of a dir, but a user space process which explicitely read the content of a dir does? What does "user-space processes explicitely read the content of a directory like ls does" look like?

Comment: `ls` is a user-space process (as opposed to kernel code reading directories to look files up from a path in  a file system) that explicitly opens and read the content of directories, so it does cause the atime of directories to be updated (on those file systems where `atime` is not disabled).

Comment: On a different linux machine, I found that the mtime of a dir doesn't change when the mtime of a file in the dir updates. Why isn't the mtime of a dir updated as well?

Comment: @Tim, isn't it exactly what you asked in [your other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187231)?

Comment: Right. sorry, I forgot.